# Getting the macOS page line printed on the monitor as a light green shadow when using Split View

Tags: display, macbook, macbook-pro, monitoring, pixels

I use [Split View](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204948) a lot with my M1 MacBook Pro (A2338). I am starting to get (*from time to time*) a green mark of the page splitter marked on my monitor as a green line. It's super weird. I'd like to know why it happens, how can I prevent it?

The monitor I am using is a Dell U2419H and I oddly do not see this same line with my Windows laptop when it’s connected to the Dell U2419H.

P.S.: I get a lot of static shocks from my Ikea desk pad or MacBook that lights or immediately turn off monitor screen. I am not sure whether this is damaging it, thought I should just inform.

[image]

Comment: If it its an M1 MacBook, I would recommend contacting Apple and allow them to check. This all seems like an underlying hardware issue and if you are still under warranty, the best bet is to simply let Apple deal with this.

Comment: Ok thanks for letting me know. if it the greenling displays on monitor but not MacBook, would it still be the MacBook problem or monitor?

Comment: Please edit your question to add the make and model number of the monitor. Oh! External display? That is an issue with the monitor end not the MacBook. I thought you were talking about the built in display on the MacBook itself. External monitor is something else.

Comment: Done. Yeah I was quite confused why it would be MacBook. Nonetheless, thanks for getting back to me and helping me out :)

Comment: You edited your post to add the model number of you MacBook and not details of your monitor? Why? Please edit your question to add the make and model number of the monitor.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 Sorry, for my late reply. I wasn't sure if it was a monitor issue as I don't see the same problem with my windows laptop. Nonetheless, the monitor is DELL U2419H.

Comment: Thanks for adding the detail! I wonder if there is a DPI issue with the display that only shows up at higher DPI. My understanding is the new MacBooks display at 144dpi while many system still use 72dpi. If the Windows laptop is displaying at 72dpi but the MacBooko is 144dpi that *might* explain why you see the issue with one machine but not the other.

Comment: Thanks for your comprehension response! I actually never heard of that term before but seems like a fair point. As I couldn't find the DPI of Dell monitors on their website, I went to https://www.infobyip.com/detectmonitordpi.php. I am not sure if that's the right of measuring, but when I tested on my laptop it showed 192 x 192 while in my monitor being 96 x 96. Does this explain the issue? if so, how should new MacBook users go about buying a monitor? As my current monitor is quite new and was excited about my UT monitor that I am expected to receive.

Comment: My best advice to you is to still contact Apple support and see if they know might be the issue here. They might push back so I would also contact Dell support and see if they have any insight. Past that, no idea. Best of luck with this!

Comment: Will do! Thanks a lot for your help :))